# Is it zina if I had oral sex with my sister?

Tags: sex

Aslamualaikum

I did oral sex with my sister at the age of 15. Not sexual inter-course. Is it equivalent to Zina?

Is there any affect on my parents marriage?

Will Allah forgive me as I am very ashamed of doing when I was younger?

Answer (score 1):

Kissing is also form of oral sex, Repent to Allah, don't repeat. Allah willing , Allah will forgive you.

No effect on your parents marriage.

I believe penetration  is the only sex that's called intercourse in Islam.

Comment: Is it equivalent to Zina,  didn't penetrate

Comment: Zina of eyes is watching pornography, women wearing strong perfumes in public is also a form of zina. Intercourse is zina in legal terminology to best of my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Asalam Alikum brother, oral is zina but repent brother by regretting the sin, apologizing sincerely to the creator of the universe and trying your best not to fall in it again. No matter if you fall again and again and again till you can't count just know if your repentance is sincere you are forgiven afterall الله is the most merciful of the merciful most forgiving of the forgiving AND DO NOT EVER SAY OH I AM SO BAD الله WONT FORGIVE ME ) it is haram to think that way and those thoughts are from the shaitian. Inshallah you be from the first in jannah al firdaus brother the reason as to why it is haram to think that way is because you are glorifying your sin over  the creator of the universe.From my knowledge i do not think there is any affect on your parents considering your age or maybe they will have a sort of punishment as they may have allowed this to happen I'm uncertain about this question